# Distribution of my data and hypothesis testing

Tags: r, distributions

I have a problem and I'm not sure what distribution my data has.

[image]

And an other question: 
Does anyone know what you call this distribution? I have to prove hypotheses (one variant is rated better than others) and cannot use anova because it requires a normal distribution.

I used the vglm function in R. I think that's the multiple regression analysis. But I still don't know exactly what I get from the results (they are significantly different ***)

I hope for an answer regarding the distribution and would appreciate a tip on the hypothesis analysis.

Comment: With such a large number of ratings, the distribution of the sample will mean will be *extremely* close to Normal and ANOVA will be perfectly applicable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Wilcoxon rank sum test (or signed rank sum test if the data are paired) to perform a hypothesis test between two groups of ordinal data like this. It is a non parametric test so there is no assumption of distribution.

Comment: Hi I cant use this because I dont have 2 groups of doing the same